# Use Multiple Columndefinitions in ListView

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I want to create a `ListView` as shown in the picture below:

[image]

The xaml looks like this

```
<ListView>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Type" >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Comment" >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value1" >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value2" >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value3" >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Value4" >
            <GridViewColumn Header="Result" >
         </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Is it possible to set the `<GridView>` with a `DataTrigger` as it can be done in a `ContentPresenter`? I could not find a property like `Style` or `Template` which I could use.

I.e. like this (not working)

```
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Style>
                    <Style>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger>
                                aso
```

Answer (score 0):

The `GridView` itself is not a `Control` and doesn't have a `Style` property.

The best thing you can do is to add a `DataTrigger` to the `ItemContainerStyle` of the `ListView` as explained in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-style-a-row-in-a-listview-that-implements-a-gridview?WT.mc_id=WD-MVP-5001077):

```
<ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}"  >
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Default}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XPath=@Rating}" Value="5">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource StronglyRecommended}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding XPath=@Rating}" Value="4">
                <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource Recommended}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
```